# Connect to specific user in SignalR without username

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I am new to SignalR. I need to develop a form that when user fill it out the representative can see her input and help her. 
Consider the user is at home and rep is at office. Also there is no authentication involve. I know there is ConnectionId that I can use but is it doable without username? In this way how I can connect rep to specific User?

Comment: If you don't have authentication enabled how anyone is supposed to know who is connecting? How are you preventing random people from connecting?

Comment: @Pawel  The form doesn't need any kind of Authentication it should be open to everyone and because of that I don't know how specify a user as I have the connection Id but because there is no username how I can find which connection belongs to which user.

Comment: In general - If no one provides the name how/where you can get the name at all? There is no name in the system. You have connection id because SignalR generates connection id but it does not generate any names - they need to come from somewhere and typically authentication is the way to go.

Comment: @Pawel I was thinking the same way. By looking at the documentation I find I need to piece of info to target a specific user – name and collection Id. So if the random user call the customer service and the representative wants to help him in the screen there is no way to connect this 2 together if there is no authentication involve.

Comment: No, you need only connection id e.g. `Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).clientMethod(arguments)`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server contains name only because the client expects it and it is somehow provided (like in the chat sample the client provides his name when starting the chat). addContosoChatMessageToPage in the article is just the client side method and you decide what arguments it takes.

Comment: @Pawel but for example this line:     Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).broadcastMessage(name, message); sent a message to same user that calls, I want to send a message to another user.

Comment: You need to know the connection id of the user you want to send the message and use it instead of `Context.ConnectionId`

Comment: @Pawel But the connectionId is associated with the browser and if the user open the new one connectionId would change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered in to looking this tutorial provided by SignalR team? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Comment: yes that is what exactly what I have started on. but what if I don't want to broadcast to all like instead of Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message); just send it to specific user. I know I have to use connectionId, but can I do without username'